# Transforming Seaborn axis to log

Tags: python, seaborn

I am plotting some data in a pandas dataframe as a simple boxplot using seaborn. I would like to use a log scale on the y axis. Is there a good way to do this?

```
from matplotlib import style, pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

plt.figure()
sns.boxplot(x='Sample', y='Variants', data=plot_data)
plt.tick_params(labelbottom=True, bottom=False)
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True, bottom=True)
```

I did try `plt.set_yscale('log')` but I just get this error: `'module' object has no attribute 'set_yscale'`

And `plt.yscale('log')` gives me a very large plot.

Comment: Did you mean `plt.yscale`? Or `plt.gca().set_yscale`?

Comment: Actually `plt.gca().set_yscale` works nicely. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Note however that you would usually call `ax=sns.blaplot()` and then use `ax` with the solutions from the duplicate